# Getting an empty array in codeigniter project

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In the code below,I'm getting an empty array for the third if-else statement. What I'm trying is that get a range of date from user and showing the data from the table accordingly. My first if-else statement is returning desired results but the second one is returning empty array.

**Controller:**

```
  public function bookings()
   {
    if($this->userlib->isLoggedIn())
    {
        if($this->userlib->isAdmin())
        {
            $this->load->view('admin_search_booking');
            $date_posted_from = $this->input->post('date_posted_from');
            $date_posted_till = $this->input->post('date_posted_till');
            $date_posted_on = $this->input->post('date_posted_on');
            if(is_null($date_posted_from) && is_null($date_posted_till) && is_null($date_posted_on))
            {
                $total_trails = $this->admin_panel_model->total_trail();    
                var_dump($total_trails);
            }
            elseif(!is_null($date_posted_on))
            {
                $total_trails = $this->admin_panel_model->filter_on_date($date_posted_on);
                var_dump($total_trails);
            }
            elseif(!is_null($date_posted_from) && !is_null($date_posted_till))
            {
                $total_trails = $this->admin_panel_model->filter_by_date($date_posted_from, $date_posted_till);
                var_dump($total_trails);
            }
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "User not Logged In";
    }
}
```

**Model** `filter_by_date` :-

```
public function filter_by_date($date_posted_from, $date_posted_till)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->where('date >=', $date_posted_from)
                      ->where('date <=', $date_posted_till)
                      ->get($this->search);
    return $query->result();
}
```

isLoggedIn :-

```
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    if($this->ci->session->email)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Try to `echo` your query and check is it working within Sql

Comment: query is working fine,checked ,actually when i remove the first ifelse,the other ifelse works just fine.

Comment: Post your `isLoggedIn` function

Comment: public function isLoggedIn()
    {
    if($this->ci->session->email)
    return true;
   else
    return false;
     }

Comment: Post it within question and not within comments

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think the `->get($this->search);` does it. Where do you set that value?

Comment: if you are getting empty array then there is no any problem with if else problem would be with result may be possible you are getting empty result set from db query

Answer (score 0):

Change your model function like this

```
public function filter_by_date($date_posted_from="", $date_posted_till="")
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*');
    if($date_posted_from)
        $this->db->where('date >=', $date_posted_from);
    if($date_posted_till)
        $this->db->where('date <=', $date_posted_till);
    $this->db->get($this->search);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: print last query and run the query in phpmyadmin and check there.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This may help you put your table name in your select statement and update where clause
public function filter_by_date($date_posted_from, $date_posted_till){
       $date_posted_from='2015-10-10';
        $date_posted_till='2015-10-16';
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('Your_Table_Name')
                          ->where("date >= '".$date_posted_from."'")
                          ->where("date <= '".$date_posted_till."'")
                          ->get($this->search);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: you are initializing values to $date_posted_from and $date_posted_till but i want them to be retrieved from controller file only

Comment: just pass your values from the controller and cal your methods i have initialize your variables just for example. comment those initialized variables.

Comment: Like this: 
$admin = new admin(); //creating object of model file
 $date_posted_from='2015-10-10';
 $date_posted_till='2015-10-16';
$list=$admin->filter_by_date($date_posted_from,$date_posted_till);

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->db->last_query(); after filter_by_date() and check what query is actually being executed. And also make sure there are records exists in the date range you are searching for.
Or simply use straight forward query,

```
$Q = $this->db->query("select * from table_name where date >='".$date_posted_from."' and date <='".$date_posted_to."'");
return $Q->result_array();
```